# error 403 url ajax direct controller code igniter 3

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I have error `http://localhost/psb/<?php echo site_url("Welcome/pendaftaran"); ?>` 403 (Forbidden)
I'm try post data from `user.js` to controller using url: `site_url`

structure
project/
----asset/
---------js/
--------------user.js
----application
---------controller/
--------------Welcome.php
user.js

```
 function daftar()
{
    var url= "<?php echo site_url('Welcome/pendaftaran')?>";
    $.ajax({
    url : url,
    type: "POST",
    data: $('#pendaftaran').serialize(),
    dataType: "JSON",
}
```

controller welcome

```
    <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
 public function pendaftaran(){
    $this->validate();
}
}
```

how to fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `js` page not supported `<?php` and `?>` php tag.

So, your `site_url` put your page `header` like

```
<script>
   var site_url = "<?php echo site_url(); ?>";
</script>
```

And then in `user.js` call `var site_url` variable :

```
function daftar() {
    $.ajax({
        context: this,
        url: site_url+"Welcome/pendaftaran",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: $('#pendaftaran').serialize()
    }).done(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }).fail(function (data) {
        console.log('failed');
    });
}
```